# error CS0119: 'Sitecore.Mvc.HtmlHelperExtensions.Sitecore(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Tags: sitecore-client, error-handling

[image: When I try to preview a webpage Events.cshtml in the experience editor I get this issue.]

[![I currently receiving these warnings. Do they have anything to do with it. Furthermore, the warnings say it can’t find Navigation.js and Sitecore.Foundation.Theming.min.js even though they are right there In the scripting folder][2]][2]gIqFa.png

I am using sitecore 9.3

[image]

Comment: Add @using Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions to your View. this should resolve your issue

Comment: When you post a question, do not include stack traces and other text in image. Post it as a text.

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue try to verify what namespaces you have included in Views/web.config, more specifically these lines:
*add namespace="Sitecore.Mvc"* and
*add namespace="Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation"*

There is also a warning regarding the MVC version that the project is referencing, could you verify what version you have set in web.config and Views/web.config?

Answer (score 0):

We have 2 options

1. you may add the missing namespace reference in your cshtml file
2. Add the namespace in the web.config file of that project